# Creating more than one channel using Agora in Flutter

Tags: flutter, video-streaming, flutter-dependencies, voice, agora.io

Can I create more than one channel at a time using Agora in Flutter?

The documentation says that for creating a channel, we need a `channelId` and to join in that channel, we need the temp `token`, `channelname`.

As per my knowledge only one `token` can be used at a time. What should I do to generate more than one token at the same time for different users?

Comment: Hey there, do you want to run multiple channels at the same time or do you want a single user to be present in multiple channels?

Comment: I want to run multiple channels at the same time

Comment: You can go through this blog: https://www.agora.io/en/blog/joining-multiple-channels-using-the-agora-flutter-sdk/ that will walk you through the process of running multiple channel at the same time.

Comment: thanks for your support, but I need to know about the token creation for multiple channels, that's my question was.